# How does line integration work in complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

In the complex line integral, we integrate along a path or curve. In the case of a closed curve how is the integral value 0. And how does singularity points affects the line integral along a closed curve?

Comment: The value is only guaranteed to be $0$ if the function is holomorphic / analytic on the region enclosed by the curve. Other functions can give whatever result you want.

Comment: As an example, take the function $f(z) = \operatorname{Re}(z)$. The integral along a closed curve in this case is equal to the area of the region enclosed by the curve.

Comment: Does the presence of singularity points inside the closed curve affect it(cauchy integral theorem)

Comment: It might. Integrating $\frac 1z$ once counterclockwise around the origin gives an answer of $2\pi i$. $\frac1{z^2}$, on the other hand, still gives you zero.

Comment: Sorry i can't get u